# pd.to_datetime format error, ValueError: '/' is a bad directive in format '%m%/%d/%Y'

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which contains a column of date, currently in string. I want to change to date format, but got an error with pd.to_datetime. Checked python date format here : https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

```
 df["dates"].unique()
 array(['09/28/2009', '10/19/2009', '10/23/2009', ..., '01/12/2019',
   '10/06/2019', '03/16/2019'], dtype=object)

 df["dates"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dates"],format = '%m%/%d/%Y')
```

got following errors:

```
 ValueError: '/' is a bad directive in format '%m%/%d/%Y'
```

If I don't use format in this function it will return:

```
 ParserError: day is out of range for month: 11/31/2013
```

Any insight for this error? Thanks.

Comment: yes, there is no novembre 31st 2013

Comment: Aside from @StevenG's comment, you have an extra `%`, try `,format = '%m/%d/%Y'`

Comment: I was not aware of there is no 11/31 until you point out. Also silly extra '%'.   If use format = '%m/%d/%Y', it just simply give  ValueError: day is out of range for month with no clue.